# Undefined CLR namespace,When Application Type is Class Library

Tags: wpf, compiler-errors, namespaces, clr

I'm working on a Class library, i need to add XAML in this class library, when i add **`xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Sympraxis.Capture.Common.Imagecontrol"`**
 I'm getting Designer Compile errors  due to the Usercontrols namespace.
I have added this kind of namespace in many application where the **Application Type was WPF class library/WPF Application**. but now i need to added XAML and refer the namespace where the application type is **Class Library**. Further this is **x86** and my bild was sucessfull before adding this namespace. i have tried so many times but stuck with for last two days.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImageOrientation"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:sys='clr-namespace:Sympraxis.Capture.Common.ImageControl'
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
```

Comment: TargetFrameWork is .NETFramework3.5 and Target CPU is x86, are u mentioning these?

Comment: oh no, i have project named Sympraxis.Capture.Common.Imagecontrol which application type is Class Library, in this project i have added the XAML file, and if i try to refer this **`xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Sympraxis.Capture.Common.Imagecontrol"`** i'm getting the error. this s my issue, i did'n get u about referenced dll.

Comment: Oh my mistake. Could you post error message as well?

Comment: Please find the following for error msg
**Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'Sympraxis.Capture.Common.Imagecontrol' that is not included in the assembly. F:\SympraxisV5o1NewTFS\MailRoom\01Dev\WIP\ImageControl\Sympraxis.Capture.Common.ImageControl\ImageOrientation.xaml**

Comment: You able to see the namespace, **Sympraxis.Capture.Common.Imagecontrol** in Class View window?

Comment: No, but usally i add the 'clr-namespace' by right click project properties and the content in Assembly name, eventhough if i give the relevent name which i'm able to see in classdiagram.cd, still i'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot see **Sympraxis.Capture.Common.Imagecontrol** in the Class view window, that means you do not have any types under that namespace in the project, Hence the compilation error. Also, from your XAML, I see the `ImageOrientation` usercontrol is not under any namespace, Is this class supposed to be under the mentioned namespace?